# Сборник задач

Tags: php

Посоветуйте, а то в моем учебнике только теория, а хочется и примеры поделать и поразбирать.

Comment: Зачем искать примеры?:) Ищем сайт -> Изучаем -> Воспроизводим функционал ;)

Comment: это пока еще слишком сложно, мне бы чего попроще)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я только встречал 2 книги с задачами:

1. Кузнецов М.В., Симдянов И.В. - Головоломки на PHP для хакера
2. Уильям С. - 75 готовых решений для вашего web-сайта на PHP (Самоучитель).

Мой совет-сидите на форуме и решайте задачи, которые задают другие участники. Действует на все 100%, но поначалу трудно.

Comment: да, последний метод знаю)спасибо)

Comment: Koza4ok , а не могли бы Вы подсказать книгу, где будет хорошо описано, как правильнее сделать поисковую систему? Просто мне кажется, что мои алгоритмы не очень хороши. Хотелось бы узнать более лучшие решения.
думаю каждый программист должен хоть раз в жизни сделать поисковую систему)

Comment: " Головоломки на PHP для хакера" тоже очень рекомендую. Постоянно лежит на столе. Хорошая книга

Answer (score 2):

Я начинал с [phpclub.ru](http://phpclub.ru/faq/Nachalo), ну а дальше были всякие мануалы "как напсиать свою гостевую книгу" и в конце концов перешел на изучение внутренностей простеньких исходников... чем дальше, тем глубже и сложнее были исходники. Так же постоянно обращался к мануалу по [php](http://php.net). В комментах бывают полезные примеры.