# Хороший онлайн-учебник по PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хороший учебник по php, желательно хорошо структурированные, как, например, http://learn.javascript.ru/ На русском или английском языке значения не имеет. Хотелось бы найти именно веб-сайт, а не пдф-книгу.

Comment: http://php.net

Comment: Для меня почему-то именно книги стали "прозрением" в `php`, а не какие-либо сайты. Почему? Да потому что на любом сайте это все как-то разрозненно стандартно (больше смахивает на техническую документацию, а то и вовсе перевод), нету т.с. "сюжетной линии", а книга по `php` как роман должна быть, читатель должен войти во вкус, заинтересоваться, заинтриговаться в конце-концов, а на сайтах еще раз повторюсь учить php - `дело тонкое`!

Comment: Для изучения php стоит учить не только php. На личном опыте знаю что очень многое в книгах изложено коротко или не достаточно ясно.  
Например Кузнецов и Симдянов "PHP 5/6" - ИМХО книга просто эпических размеров, но есть ряд моментов которые плохо разобраны.  
Лично я вдогонку читал java, C, заглянул в ruby и perl и ещё много чего...

Comment: Нужна новая формулировка закрытия: провоцирует спам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я очень люблю покупать книжки по ЯП. Почему-то мне удобно читать именно бумажные такие книги.
Сначала я купил "Сценарии для Web-сайта. PHP и JavaScript" (Вадим Дунаев) , а Кузнецов М.В., Симдянов И.В. - Головоломки на PHP для хакера .
С первой книгой я просто понял что такое php и с чем его едят. А во второй книжке разбирал готовые ответы в конце книги.
Больше по php я не читал книг. Разве что прихожу на сайт php.net , чтобы узнать какую-либо функцию.

Так что думаю не стоит искать другие источники. Узнавайте на php.net.
Еще полезно прочитать эту [тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150707/php-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87)

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится [php.su](http://php.su), там как учебник есть + краткая информация о каждой функции с примером.

Comment: если не обращать внимание, что информация отстаёт на несколько версий языка, то php.su будет одним из пары нормальных ресурсов про php на русском.

Answer (score 1):

в [php.net](http://php.net) наиболее полный справочник, там снизу есть комментарии в котором даются еще куча примеров помимо официальной документации